# Is asn1 definition proivided by Google valid one?

Tags: android, language-lawyer, asn.1

**Is ASN.1 definition provided by google on https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation#attestation-v3 valid one?**

```
KeyDescription ::= SEQUENCE {
    attestationVersion  3,
    attestationSecurityLevel  SecurityLevel,
    keymasterVersion  INTEGER,
    keymasterSecurityLevel  SecurityLevel,
    attestationChallenge  OCTET_STRING,
    uniqueId  OCTET_STRING,
    softwareEnforced  AuthorizationList,
    teeEnforced  AuthorizationList,
}

SecurityLevel ::= ENUMERATED {
    Software  (0),
    TrustedEnvironment  (1),
    StrongBox  (2),
}

AuthorizationList ::= SEQUENCE {
    purpose  [1] EXPLICIT SET OF INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    algorithm  [2] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    keySize  [3] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    digest  [5] EXPLICIT SET OF INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    padding  [6] EXPLICIT SET OF INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    ecCurve  [10] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    rsaPublicExponent  [200] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    rollbackResistance  [303] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
    activeDateTime  [400] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    originationExpireDateTime  [401] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    usageExpireDateTime  [402] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    noAuthRequired  [503] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
    userAuthType  [504] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    authTimeout  [505] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    allowWhileOnBody  [506] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
    trustedUserPresenceRequired  [507] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
    trustedConfirmationRequired  [508] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
    unlockedDeviceRequired  [509] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
    allApplications  [600] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
    applicationId  [601] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    creationDateTime  [701] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    origin  [702] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    rootOfTrust  [704] EXPLICIT RootOfTrust OPTIONAL,
    osVersion  [705] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    osPatchLevel  [706] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    attestationApplicationId  [709] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    attestationIdBrand  [710] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    attestationIdDevice  [711] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    attestationIdProduct  [712] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    attestationIdSerial  [713] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    attestationIdImei  [714] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    attestationIdMeid  [715] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    attestationIdManufacturer  [716] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    attestationIdModel  [717] EXPLICIT OCTET_STRING OPTIONAL,
    vendorPatchLevel  [718] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
    bootPatchLevel  [719] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
}

RootOfTrust ::= SEQUENCE {
    verifiedBootKey  OCTET_STRING,
    deviceLocked  BOOLEAN,
    verifiedBootState  VerifiedBootState,
    verifiedBootHash OCTET_STRING,
}

VerifiedBootState ::= ENUMERATED {
    Verified  (0),
    SelfSigned  (1),
    Unverified  (2),
    Failed  (3),
}
```

cause to make it work with python `asn1tools` and https://asn1.io/asn1playground/ I had to:

- remove dangling comas,
- change `attestationVersion  3` to `attestationVersion  INTEGER`,
- `OCTET_STRING` to `OCTET STRING`,
- and all enumerated keys to camelCase.

```
ASN1 DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
    KeyDescription ::= SEQUENCE {
        attestationVersion  INTEGER,
        attestationSecurityLevel  SecurityLevel,
        keymasterVersion  INTEGER,
        keymasterSecurityLevel  SecurityLevel,
        attestationChallenge  OCTET STRING,
        uniqueId  OCTET STRING,
        softwareEnforced  AuthorizationList,
        teeEnforced  AuthorizationList
    }

    SecurityLevel ::= ENUMERATED {
        software  (0),
        trustedEnvironment  (1),
        strongBox  (2)
    }

    AuthorizationList ::= SEQUENCE {
        purpose  [1] EXPLICIT SET OF INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        algorithm  [2] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        keySize  [3] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        digest  [5] EXPLICIT SET OF INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        padding  [6] EXPLICIT SET OF INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        ecCurve  [10] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        rsaPublicExponent  [200] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        rollbackResistance  [303] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
        activeDateTime  [400] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        originationExpireDateTime  [401] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        usageExpireDateTime  [402] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        noAuthRequired  [503] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
        userAuthType  [504] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        authTimeout  [505] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        allowWhileOnBody  [506] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
        trustedUserPresenceRequired  [507] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
        trustedConfirmationRequired  [508] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
        unlockedDeviceRequired  [509] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
        allApplications  [600] EXPLICIT NULL OPTIONAL,
        applicationId  [601] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        creationDateTime  [701] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        origin  [702] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        rootOfTrust  [704] EXPLICIT RootOfTrust OPTIONAL,
        osVersion  [705] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        osPatchLevel  [706] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        attestationApplicationId  [709] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        attestationIdBrand  [710] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        attestationIdDevice  [711] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        attestationIdProduct  [712] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        attestationIdSerial  [713] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        attestationIdImei  [714] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        attestationIdMeid  [715] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        attestationIdManufacturer  [716] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        attestationIdModel  [717] EXPLICIT OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
        vendorPatchLevel  [718] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL,
        bootPatchLevel  [719] EXPLICIT INTEGER OPTIONAL
    }

    RootOfTrust ::= SEQUENCE {
        verifiedBootKey  OCTET STRING,
        deviceLocked  BOOLEAN,
        verifiedBootState  VerifiedBootState,
        verifiedBootHash OCTET STRING
    }

    VerifiedBootState ::= ENUMERATED {
        verified  (0),
        selfSigned  (1),
        unverified  (2),
        failed  (3)
    }
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corrections you made are necessary. The first ASN.1 specification above contains all the errors that you listed.

Comment: So, it is not some weird extension, or next version of the notation, but just a invalid code?

Comment: Alessandro is correct.  Using OCTET-STRING would be valid if somewhere OCTET-STRING were defined as a type, but the built-in type is "OCTET STRING".  OCTET_STRING would not be valid because underscores are not used in ASN.1

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you have to fix this specification is that is not meant for a tool but only for a human reader.

Before the errors you mentioned, you will have noticed there is no module definition (just assignments) which is a very bad start. The tagging default is essential for the validation of the tags.

This specification is plain text and is not used as an input file to an asn.1 tool anywhere.

In their [sample](https://github.com/google/android-key-attestation), Google are using Bouncycastle library (so they don't need a valid specification for that)

Still, it does not hurt to validate asn.1 specifications or asn.1 assignments (in this case) when it's published in an article ...